# Position all agenda files in tabbar group emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm using tabbar to define groups of files.
Some are in the "Emacs buffer" group, others are in the "Dired" group and all others, ATM, are in the "User buffer" group.

I would like to add another group for when I'm using the agenda files - 
Instead of having the files all appear in the "User buffer" and litter my tabs view, I would like them to appear in a destined group called "Agenda buffers".
How could that be done?

At the moment this is my configuration:

```
(defun tabbar-buffer-groups ()
  "Return the list of group names the current buffer belongs to.
This function is a custom function for tabbar-mode's tabbar-buffer-groups.
This function group all buffers into 3 groups:
Those Dired, those user buffer, and those emacs buffer.
Emacs buffer are those starting with “*”."
  (list
   (cond
    ((string-equal "*" (substring (buffer-name) 0 1)) "Emacs Buffer")
    ((eq major-mode 'dired-mode) "Dired")
    ((eq major-mode 'sr-mode) "Dired")
    (t "User Buffer")
    )))

(setq tabbar-buffer-groups-function 'tabbar-buffer-groups)
```

Comment: What are agenda files? org files, the `*Org Agenda*` buffer?

Comment: All files in org-agenda-files list.

Comment: Comment: better use `(derived-mode-p 'dired-mode)` instead of `(eq major-mode 'dired-mode)`.

Comment: Thanks. Can I also somehow combine dired-mode and sr-mode in the same rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a condition to the function as follows:

```
(defun tabbar-buffer-groups ()
  "Return the list of group names the current buffer belongs to.
This function is a custom function for tabbar-mode's tabbar-buffer-groups.
This function group all buffers into 3 groups:
Those Dired, those user buffer, and those emacs buffer.
Emacs buffer are those starting with “*”."
  (list
   (cond
    ((string-equal "*" (substring (buffer-name) 0 1)) "Emacs Buffer")
    ((member (buffer-file-name) (mapcar 'expand-file-name org-agenda-files)) "Agenda")
    ((eq major-mode 'dired-mode) "Dired")
    ((eq major-mode 'sr-mode) "Dired")
    (t "User Buffer")
    )))
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Opening Todo.org opens it in the User buffer still, or using agenda view, for that matter.

Comment: Ah yes you have to extract the buffer name from the filename. Try the new version.

Comment: You are probably using the `~` symbol in your `org-agenda-files` variable. You need to compare the canonical representations of the file names. The new edit should do that.

Comment: However, if you have put a directory in the `org-agenda-files` variable you will need to refine it. This solution works only for files.

Comment: Superb. Now it works. It's just files now, so it's OK:) I use ~ in the setq org-directory. What else can I do?

Comment: You could check if an element is a directory in `org-agenda-files`. If this is the case, instead of checking with `member` you would check with `file-in-directory-p`.